# Date range selection when graphing a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, graphing

Here is the following code for my scatter plot.

The date are ranges from 1-01-2015 to 03-01-2022. How can I adjust the code to only view specific date ranges such as 01-01-2015 to 12-30-2015?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Outliers.xlsx', 'ATL')

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(10,6,))
ax.scatter(x=df['HDDs'], y = df['UPBU'], c='blue')

plt.xlabel("HDDs")
plt.ylabel("Use Per Billing Unit")
plt.title("LDC HDD Vs. UPBU")
plt.show()
```

Here are the outputs for the above script:

print(df.head())

```
        Date HDDs     UPBU
0 2015-01-01 17.0 0.457539
1 2015-01-02 16.5 0.429936
2 2015-01-03  7.3 0.311634 
3 2015-01-04 16.6 0.432595 
4 2015-01-05 26.8 0.703082
```

print(df.tail())

```
           Date HDDs     UPBU
2642 2022-03-27 11.6 0.311739
2643 2022-03-28  7.5 0.267713 
2644 2022-03-29  0.2 0.165169 
2645 2022-03-30  0.0 0.118345 
2646 2022-03-31  4.7 0.154248
```

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEcGt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the date column to show only the required dates. Use the filter in the `ax.scatter()` so that only those dates are picked up. Updated code below. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Outliers.xlsx', 'ATL')

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(10,6,))
ax.scatter(x=df[(df['Date'] >= '01-01-2015') & (df['Date'] <= '12-30-2015')]['HDDs'], 
           y = df[(df['Date'] >= '01-01-2015') & (df['Date'] <= '12-30-2015')]['UPBU'], 
           c='blue')

plt.xlabel("HDDs")
plt.ylabel("Use Per Billing Unit")
plt.title("LDC HDD Vs. UPBU")
plt.show()
```